# What is the unit of window size in Konsole?

Tags: kde, window, konsole

When one opens a Konsole window or resizes it, window sizes appear at the centre. For example, if one opens Konsole it says 110×28. What is the unit of window size?

[image]

Comment: Edited your question to refer to Konsole only, because that thing you're referring to only exists within the KDE Konsole program (and in embedded KDE konsole components).

Answer (score 1):

That's "text cells", i.e. the size of the console in characters. It's 110 characters wide, 28 high.

It only applies to Konsole. It doesn't generally exist in KDE.

Comment: I have added an image to the question to reflect it more properly. And, how to convert it to pixels? I have tried `root.configure(width=console.font.measure("0") * 110, height=console.font.measure("0") * 28)` on Tkinter but it did not work as expected.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. How does tkinter come into this? Konsole is not written using Tk, but using Qt, and not in Python but C++. So, um, this all makes no sense? Please ask a new question, describing exactly what you need to know. Don't ask new things in comments!

Comment: You are saying that it is characters. So, it should be char*110 and char*28 in pixels but it did not work. Are you sure it is characters? Or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I say what I say, right. what you write makes no sense. Please follow the advice I gave in my comment and ask a new question in which you, in detail, describe what you are trying to do, show your full code, and explain how you arrive at your solution. "char*110 and char*28"  really makes **no** sense at all.